# How to create, design and throw built-in Error objects

Tags: javascript, firebug

**UPDATE**

---

[Rewriting question to focus on the problem I am trying to understand.]

Is there a means in JavaScript to throw Exceptions that notify the line number where the problem occurs?  Similar to C#'s debugger, if an error is thrown on line 50 then I will be taken to line 50.

For example, according to [MDN](http://www.google.com/search?q=evalerror&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) `EvalError` represents an error with `eval()`.  So, let's say I have a function that uses `eval()`.  I want to use a specific error that is representative of the problem at hand, `EvalError`:

```
//As written here the error implies there is a problem on this line.  See Firebug console window
var evalErra = new EvalError('required element missing from evaluation');

var stringFunc = "a=2;y=3;document.write(x*y);";

EvalString(stringFunc);

function EvalString(stringObject) {
    //Some arbitrary check, for arguments sake let's say checking for 'x' makes this eval() valid.
    if(stringObject.indexOf('x') !== -1) {
        throw evalErra;
        //throw 'required element missing from evaluation';//This way offers no line number
    }
    eval(stringFunc);//The problem really lies in the context of this function.
}
```

If I'm going about this all wrong, then please tell me how I should approach these kinds of issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you throw an error, execution of the current code will stop and JS will work its way back up the execution tree until it finds a `catch ()` which handles the particular type of error being thrown, or gets all the way up to the top of the tree, causing an "unhandled exception" error: You threw an error, and nothing caught it, and now someone's window got broken.

```
try {
   if (true) {
      throw 'yup'
   }
} catch (e) { // catches all errors
   ... handle the error
}
```

Comment: Why do I see a difference between the uncaught literal string error and the uncaught typed error, EvalError?

Comment: you can throw anything you want. In the 'yup' case, you're throwing a  hardcoded string, which is basically meaningless. It could be `throw 'woah, true was not true'`  which'd be a bit more helpful. As for the EvalError, you're throwing the whole object, and the only time that object's been used/referred to is the line where it's instantiated, so that's where the error gets reported.

Comment: Updated question to try to narrow the scope down to the issue I want solved.

Comment: Try doing `throw new EvalError('required element missing')` instead. EvalError seems to embed the line number where it was instantiated, which means that when you throw it, it'll point at the wrong place. But otherwise, it should be thrown automatically if eval fails. so `try { eval(...) } catch (EvalError) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

When doing error handling you want to do the following

`throw new Error("message");`

Then if you ever handle this error look at `err.stack` (firefox/opera/chrome) or `err.line` (Safari) or `err.IE_Y_U_NO_SHOW_ME_ERROR_LINE_NUMBER` (IE) to find the line number.

If you want you can subclass `Error`.